# Identify orphan nodes in the DOM and remove them! Memory leaks of orphan DOM nodes

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, memory-leaks

Do you know of any good way to identify all the orphan nodes and remove them from DOM?

My problem is that i have a huge application with many controls and some of them are orphans and cause memory leaks.

So is there a good way fix that?

Thanks

*P.S according to sIEve documentation*

***Orphan:** if the value in this column is “Yes” then the element is not attached to the document.body. IE then it is a orphan node. In IE this Elements can leak as well so special care should be taken on this kinds of elements. For example clearing/setting the innerHTML of orphan nodes will cause pseudo leaks. Also orphan nodes will not fire 
‘onpropertychange’ events.* (Zahid Riaz)

Comment: How you can say a dom node is orphan???

Comment: I am testing the application in sIEve and it shows me that the leaks are coming from orphan nodes.

Comment: Its still unable to say that dom node is orphan? How one can predict that node is orphan? There must exist some condition

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. take a look at the image on the link. [screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/4lecdgrsb/)

Comment: What is sIEve? What column does that quote refer to? Do you mean DOM element that are not attached to a DOM tree?

Comment: How can you remove an element from the DOM that already *isn't attached to* the DOM?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas sIEve is a software that shows if a web application has leaks + other things. I have nodes that are not in the DOM and are leaking, which makes the IE memory to continuously go up. I want to know if there is a way to find them and add them to the DOM so i can then remove them.

Comment: @DavidThomas Please refer to the comment i posted above. Thanks

Comment: @Solon Why are those nodes not in the DOM? What code created them? Btw, the way garbage collection works in browsers is, it doesn't matter if a node is in the DOM or not; what matters is if there exists at least one reference to the node. As long as a node is referenced from some other place, it will not be garbage collected. I think your issue can be resolved by `null`-ing certain bindings.

Comment: @Solon Also, not that the state your nodes are currently in, is the same state that would be achieved if you were to remove them from the DOM. A node can either be attached to the DOM, or detached from the DOM. So, if you add a node to the DOM only to remove if from the DOM right away, you haven't changed anything. You have to kill the references to the node in order for it do be garbage collected.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas There is a reference to many controls... It's a huge application and many people worked on it and there is no way to know which elements are orphans so I cannot make them null!

Comment: @Solon Are those references actually used? So, if you have a control which is an orphan, and if you have other controls referencing that orphan, are those other controls actually using that orphan, or are their references to the orphan useless?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas At the point of leaving the page or post back the references are useless. The real problem occurs when I have a partial post back event fired in an iFrame.

Comment: @Solon If the references are not useless, i.e. if the other controls use the orphan (or at least have potential to do so), then the orphan should obviously *not* be garbage collected. In that case, you don't really have a memory-leak... it's just that you have many controls which take up a lot of memory. If, however, an orphan-control should not be used anymore, then you must **explicitly** kill all references to it in order for it to be garbage collected.

Comment: So, once a control is to be removed, you have to kill all references to it. Then, after removing all controls in such a manner, if the app still takes up too much memory, you'll have to consider taking measures to reduce the amount of controls in the app.

Comment: That being said, I believe older versions of IE have issues with circular references, e.g. when an event handler references the event target (so that you have to kill all handlers before removing the element itself) or something like that. I recommend that you google-research this topic.

Comment: Thank you @ŠimeVidas i will read a bit more into it! Thanks again for the information you provided!

Answer (score 0):

**I have an idea for you to test with sIEve:**

If you are creating DOM elements as such:

`$('body').append('<div>foo</div>');`

Try doing this [instead]:

```
var elm = document.createElement('div');
elm.innerHTML = 'foo';
$(document.body).append(elm); //or document.body.appendChild(elm);
```

*Then* run your memory leak checking plug-in again and see what happens. *(I'm personally curious.)*